# How to translate Customer dashboard "Account Information" Tab text in magneto 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, translate

I'm trying to translate Magento 2.4 with Porto theme in Danish, all translations working fine but a few of them not work.

1. Under Customer Dashboard > Account Information below text not translated.
   "In order to reset your password, please [Sign Out](/default/customer/account/logout/) and click on “Forgot Your Password?” from the Sign In page"
   [image]
2. Backorder message not translated, in vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableCondition

```
if ($displayQty > 0) {
       $errors = [
         $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory->create([
            'code' => 'back_order-not-enough',
            'message' => __(
                'We don\'t have as many quantity as you requested, '
                . 'but we\'ll back order the remaining %1.',
                $displayQty * 1
                )])
       ];
       return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => $errors]);
    }
```

Also is there any way to show backorder message in popup on the checkout page?

3. All .js error messages also not translated into danish.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Faizan Roshan

Comment: Translation message added in which csv file? can you please add file path?

Comment: In app/i18n and app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/i18n da_DK.csv

Comment: Translation i put in .csv file "We don\'t have as many quantity as you requested, but we\'ll back order the remaining %1.","Vi har ikke så mange mængder, som du har anmodet om, men vi bestiller tilbage den resterende %1.",module,Magento_InventorySales"

Comment: "In order to reset your password, please","translated text"

Comment: "and click on “Forgot Your Password?” from the Sign In page","translated text"

Comment: above translation message for password reset in account information                             "In order to reset your password, please Sign Out and click on “Forgot Your Password?” from the Sign In page"

Comment: If inspect element code helps<p>
         <br>
        In order to reset your password, please <a href="http://sample.com/default/customer/account/logout/">Sign Out</a> and click on “Forgot Your Password?” from the Sign In page    </p>

Comment: Did you solve this? I cannot seem to override this backorder message.